# How can I use my iPhone 3G economically in China?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I'm traveling to China and would like to use my iPhone there. I would not like to pay AT&T's crazy and predatory charges. What should I do? I don't have much time and want something low on the 'things can go wrong' scale. Oh, and I have a dinosaur 3G, and a 4G.

Comment: People's Republic of China (communist china) or Republic Of China (Taiwan)?

Comment: People normally refer to the PRC as "China" and the ROC as "Taiwan".

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on airplane mode, but enable WiFi (Or you could get an iPad with only WiFi), then make calls through FaceTime, or Skype equivalent.

Impossible that you could be charged, but you would have to be near a Wi-Fi source for it to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Cellular Network, 3G and Data roaming. You can still use regular telephone calling and texting.

If you find WiFi you can use Whatsapp or iMessage for texting, and Viber or Skype for calling.